# PIL Image.fromArray's color space

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-space

I have an image I created from an array of RGB values. Something like
`[(104, 104, 104), (56, 72, 81), ...]`

In order to do this, I used the Image.fromArray method in PIL.
However, I have no idea what color space PIL uses for this - the ICC profile is nonexistent and the "mode" of the image is "L".

Can someone please tell me what the color space of the PIL images are?
Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't use any color space—so the it's just using what I suppose you could call a naive (or _device-dependent_) [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn’t create an RGB image. You created a grayscale image. To create a color image, you meet an array with the correct shape. Something like this:

```
[[(r,g,b), (r,g,b), ...],
 [(r,g,b), (r,g,b), ...],
 ...]
```

The `L` means grayscale.

If you create an RGB image it won’t have an explicit color space. If you want it to have a color space you have to specify it.